# Sum different elements of a same list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the type list={1,2...,n,n+1,...,2n,2n+1,...,3n,..} and I want to create a new list with the sum of certain elements of the list, in the way newlist = {1+(n+1)+(2n+1)...,2+(2n+1)+(3n+1)...}, for example:

`list = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5}`, `newlist={1+1+1,2+2+2,3+3+3,4+4+4,5+5+5}`,

I tried using `listnew1=Table[Take[list[[i,1]],{i,1,n}]`, `listnew2=Table[Take[list[[i,1]],{i,n+1,2n}]` and so on, and then

```
total=listnew1+listnew2 +...
```

the problem comes for a several listnew (in my case around 1000)

is there a way to this in mathematica automatically?
Thanks for the help,

Comment: So you have a list of length $k\cdot n$ and want to sum every $n$th element to produce a list of $k$ such sums?

Comment: If it's every fifth element, then `Total@Partition[list, 5]`. If it's every `n`th element, then `Total@Partition[list, n]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's every `n`th element, then

```
Total@Partition[list, n]
```

works. For example:

```
lst = Array[a, 12]
Total@Partition[lst, 4]
(* {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], a[10], a[11], a[12]}
(* {a[1] + a[5] + a[9], a[2] + a[6] + a[10], a[3] + a[7] + a[11], a[4] + a[8] + a[12]} *)
```

Less elegantly, using `Table` and `Sum`:

```
With[{n = 4},
  Table[Sum[lst[[jj + kk]], {kk, 1, Length@lst, n}], {jj, 0, n - 1}]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach might be

```
n = 3;
Total /@ Table[list[[i ;; -1 ;; n]], {i, 1, n}]
```